# Java: Int cannot be converted into variable and variable cannot be converted into int

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Currency Converter in Java using while statements as well as using a scanner. I thought I had it set up but it says the int cannot be converted to my variable (meme) and the variable (meme) cannot be converted to an int.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MemeRunner
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int currency;
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        Meme m = sc.nextInt();


        System.out.println("Welcome to Currency Converter! ");
        System.out.print("Enter your currency ");

        while(currency >= 0)
        {
            System.out.println(currency);
            currency = sc.nextInt(m);
        }
        System.out.println("Change Maker Program");

        Meme coin = new Meme(99);
        System.out.println(coin);

        Meme change = new Meme(41);
        System.out.println(change);

        Meme money = new Meme(33);
        System.out.println(money);
    }
}
```

Here is my public class. The first is the runner. Maybe this will provide more info.

```
public class Meme
{
    private int totalCents;

    public Meme()
    {
        totalCents = 0;
    }

    public Meme(int cents)
    {
        totalCents = cents;
    }

    public int getDollars ()
    {
        int dollars;
        dollars = totalCents / 100;
        totalCents = totalCents % 100;
        return dollars;
    }

    public int getQuarters ()
    {
        int quarters;
        quarters = totalCents / 25;
        totalCents = totalCents % 25;
        return quarters;
    }

    public int getDimes ()
    {
        int dimes;
        dimes = totalCents / 10;
        totalCents = totalCents % 10;
        return dimes;
    }

    public int getNickels ()
    {
        int nickels;
        nickels = totalCents / 5;
        totalCents = totalCents % 5;
        return nickels;
    }

    public int getPennies ()
    {
        int pennies;
        pennies = totalCents;
        return pennies;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "Total Currency: " + totalCents + "\n ";
        result += "Dollars: " + getDollars() + "\n ";
        result += "Quarters: " + getQuarters() + "\n ";
        result += "Dimes: " + getDimes() + "\n ";
        result += "Nickels: " + getNickels() + "\n ";
        result += "Pennies: " + getPennies() + "\n ";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `sc.nextInt();` is going to return an integer, why do you think you can use it as your object `Meme`? We don't even see what `Meme` is, since you didn't include it in your code. Maybe if you have a constructor `public Meme(int i)`, then you could do `Meme m = new Meme(sc.nextInt());`, but we can't really help without more information/code.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? Why do you think it should be possible to convert a `Meme` instance to or from an `int`?

Comment: so does your Programm throw an exception or?

Comment: nextInt() returns an int. You're trying to store this int in a variable of type Meme. How could that work?

Comment: Bc I am new to java. How do I fix it?

Comment: C:\Users\james\Documents\Java\meme\MemeRunner.java:11: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Meme Meme m = sc.nextInt();
                     ^
C:\Users\james\Documents\Java\meme\MemeRunner.java:20: error: incompatible types: Meme cannot be converted to int
   currency = sc.nextInt(m);

Comment: @JamesThompson It's preferable to edit your question to add additonal information, such as error messages or additional code.

Comment: By using variables of type int to store int values. And by reading the documentation of the methods you're using, to understand what they do and what they return and what they take as argument: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Comment: @AntonH I added the other class for additional info on what the object Meme represents

Answer (score 0):

Your `Meme` class has a constructor that takes in an int. So you should be able to do:

```
Meme m = new Meme(sc.nextInt());
```

This object `m` needs to be treated like the object that it is. Thus, you can't use it like an int. So you can't do `currency = sc.nextInt(m);`, and would have to replace it with something like:

```
currency = sc.nextInt(m.getValue()); // replace getValue() with whatever the name of your method is
```

Side note (after editing of your `Meme` class): your `get...` seem to lack consistency. All of them reduce the amount of `totalCents` *except for* getPennies, which keeps the amount before and after the call. I don't know if this is desired behaviour, but I don't believe it is, since it means that calling your `toString` method will just reduce the amount in `totalCents` just for printing.

Comment: Well I could do it differently like making pennies have the mod for all of the previous get statements but both ways work the same and runs without error however the runner is the issue

Comment: @JamesThompson The side note was just to bring to your attention a potential logic issue. What you do with that info is up to you. Did my solution help? And what do you mean by **runner**?